# Is integral of energy-momentum tensor in QFT over a region $R$ self-adjoint?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, hilbert-space, mathematical-physics

Consider a quantum field theory in flat 1+1D spacetime for simplicity. Let $T_{\mu\nu}$ be the conserved symmetric stress tensor. One writes operators by integrating the tensor over the whole space, such as the Hamiltonian
$$
H = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} T_{00} (x)dx
$$
which I believe are self-adjoint operators (I don't know of a proof).

[I understand that usually when dealing with operators in QM this isn't even a question, but when operators are unbounded, distinction between Hermitian and self-adjoint operators becomes very non-trivial.]

What can one say about the integral of $T_{\mu\nu}$ over a finite region $R$ such as $[0,1]$?
$$
O_{\mu\nu} = \int_R T_{\mu\nu} dx
$$
Would it be self adjoint? What would be the appropriate domain $\mathcal{D}$ of the operator?